# How do I make my heading image show at it's full height without adding padding to elements inside of it?

Tags: html, css, image, height, background-image

Example I made:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f40e50yo/3/)

I want the background image on my header to always be 100% of the photo's height. I am just unsure how to do this without adding a ton of padding to the H2 on top of the image. I guess another question I would have is how do I make the background image fullscreen no matter what device it is on?

Here is what I am trying. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.heading {
    background: url("http://www.lexcenter.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/dt-nimble/images/backgrounds/header/art-header-main/full/r_atr-header-main.jpg");
height: 100%;
/* background-size: cover; */
}

.heading h2 {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making heading background image try below code

```
.heading {
  background: url("http://www.lexcenter.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/dt-nimble/images/backgrounds/header/art-header-main/full/r_atr-header-main.jpg");
  background-size: container; /* background size will be equal to your content */
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.heading h2 {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0; /* reset the default margin for header tags */
}
```

For background image full screen no matter what device it is on try below code

```
* {    /* reset all the default margins and padding */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.background-bg {
  width: 100%
  height: 100vh; /* height will be equal to viewport.*/
  background-image: url("background-image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your .heading a height of 100vh;

```
.height{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('http://www.lexcenter.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/dt-nimble/images/backgrounds/header/art-header-main/full/r_atr-header-main.jpg');
}
```

you can style it some more too. I think this is more like what your thinking about?

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

.height {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/949097/pexels-photo-949097.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```